# Gulp only watches main scss and not partials

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-sass

I have a problem setting up my gulp task to automatically watch my scss changes. I am creating a express app and I have a folder like this :

[image: my file setup]

First I run my gulp task in the terminal `gulp watch`. Basically, when I  add another css condition like `body {height: 25%;}` and save my partials, it doesn't convert it to css. It only works with the main.scss file. But with the `_` (partial scss) it doesn't.

Here is my gulpfile.js

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');


gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('public/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' })) // Using gulp-sass
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/stylesheets'))
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('public/sass/**/*.scss', gulp.parallel('sass', function (done) {
        // do more stuff
        done();
    }))
})
```

I tried changing the globs like `*.scss` , `**/*.scss` , `*.+(scss|sass)` but it doesn't work.

Please help

Comment: I assume all your partials are imported into main.scss?  Are you saying that the 'sass' task is not triggered when you make a change to one of the partials?  By definition there will be no output other than a change to main.scss when modifying an imported partial.  There is nothing wrong with your code but I would definitely change that 'watch' gulp.parallel to gulp.series.  Series is much better there.

Comment: okay, let me try series.

Comment: What the heck! it works now! Thank you for this.!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks ok for me. Did you import all the partials like this?

### main.scss

```css
@import 'auth';
@import 'blog-show';

/* more imports ... */
```

Comment: Yes, I imported it like that in the `main.scss` . Also, when I used it on sass like this in the terminal `sass public/sass:public/stylsheets --watch --style compressed` it works and all the partials are watched. But in gulp, it's not working.

Comment: my problem is solved. Thank you. I changed `.parallel` to `.series` as said by @Mark.

Comment: ah ok, nice. Thx for your feedback